# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos⁡(3x)}{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos⁡(3x)}{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos^2 (x)-\cos^2 (3x)}{\cos^2(x)- \cos^2(2x)}$$

Comment: The question is not clear, please fix that and add some detail about your effort on that.

Comment: Also the answer is supposed to be 8/3.1 is not the answer and I really don't know what do to next from (cos^2(x)−cos^2(3x))/(cos^2(x)−cos^2(2x)).

Comment: It is a not hard problem. To avoid downvotes and closure please add more details to your question and in particular your effort and work on that.

Comment: @gimusi I understand that but I don't know how to write limits like you do.What software do you use to write limits like that?I tried word and I couldn't copy paste my limit.I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Note that

\begin{align*}\frac{\cos x-\cos 3x}{\cos x-\cos 2x} &= \frac{\cos x-\cos 3x}{\cos x-\cos 2x}\cdot\frac{\cos x+\cos 3x}{\cos x+\cos 2x}\cdot \frac{\cos x+\cos 2x}{\cos x+\cos 3x}\\& = \frac{\cos^2 x-\cos^2 3x}{\cos^2 x-\cos^2 2x}\cdot \frac{\cos x+\cos 2x}{\cos x+\cos 3x}.\end{align*}

Use this together with

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos x+\cos 2x}{\cos x+\cos 3x} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$$

Comment: Your work is fine and you are of course free to answer as you prefer, but as a suggestion, let consider to give not a full complete answer at first but a good hint in order to let some work by the asker. Bye

Comment: Thank you for your insight. You are right I will consider this better in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that.

Comment: @gimusi your answer is wrong.The answer should be 8/3 and not 1.That is why I'm stuck with the limit at this function (cos^2(x)−cos^2(3x))/(cos^2(x)−cos^2(2x))...I  don't know if I should try the fundamental theory of trigonometry  sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1 but I have the feeling that I will be stuck again.

Comment: Do you mean that the limit of $\frac{\cos x+\cos 2x}{\cos x+\cos 3x}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ should be $8/3$? For that is not the case (note that this is not the same expression as your question).

Comment: If we write $f(x) = \frac{\cos x-\cos 3x}{\cos x-\cos 2x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{\cos^2 x-\cos^2 3x}{\cos^2 x-\cos^2 2x}$ then what is above shows that $$f(x) = g(x)\cdot \frac{\cos x+\cos 2x}{\cos x+\cos 3x}$$

Comment: @OlofRubin the limit is (cos(x)-cos(3x))/(cos(x)-cos(2x)) as x tends to 0.I used a limit calculator from google and I saw that the answer is 8/3.Is that incorrect?

Comment: @OlofRubin Sorry I firstly didn't follow your work since I misunderstood the answer since it was not properly written! Your hint was fine!

Comment: @wolly Just follow the hint given from Olof and me and you'll be able to solve the question. Try to follow each step and ask for specific clarification if it is not clear. Googoling the result is not a good way to understand and learn limits.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}$=
$\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(3x)}{\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(2x)}$=
$\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{1-\sin^2(x)-1+\sin^2(3x)}{\\1-\sin^2(x)-1+\sin^2(2x)}$

Comment: I also tried this but I wasn't sure if this was a good way to solve.

Comment: Uh I hope I get some answers because I'm not sure what do to from that limit.

Comment: @OlofRubin where did the fraction of cos(x)+cos(2x)/cos(x)+cos(3x)} come from?

Comment: It appeared through an algebraic manipulation. Did you understand these steps?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To complete the nice suggestion given by Olof, we have that

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos⁡(3x)}{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}=\frac{\cos(x)-1+1-\cos⁡(3x)}{\cos(x)-1+1-\cos(2x)}=\frac{-\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}+9\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{9x^2}}{-\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}+4\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{4x^2}}$$

then use standard limit as $t \to 0$

$$\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2} \to \frac12$$

Comment: and where is the 8/3?How do you even know that this is the correct answer?

Comment: @wolly Yes the result is indeed $8/3$, did you try to follow the given hint?