# Trigonometry limit from last time

Tags: calculus

$\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}$=
$\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(3x)}{\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(2x)}$=
$\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{1-\sin^2(x)-1+\sin^2(3x)}{\\1-\sin^2(x)-1+\sin^2(2x)}$
Is this how you solve the limit?
I also tried to understand the other part with $\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(2x)}{\cos(x)+\cos(3x)}$
Where did this function come from?There were some answers last time but they didn't explain me anything.

Comment: It's not how I'd so it; I'd just use the Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard limit problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971229/hard-limit-problem)

Comment: @wolly The answer to the question was alredy fully addressed in the previous answer, you can ask for clarifications on the previous OP whitout open a new question.

Comment: @gimusi I did asked but no one answered...

Comment: @Nosrati maybe if you can help me too I promise I won't create other questions...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Re-posting a question is not the way to draw more attention to it. Instead, you should edit your [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971229/409) with additional information and/or notes about what you find unsatisfactory about the answers you have received. Also, note that Math.SE is a high-traffic site (duplicate postings don't help); unfortunately, it's possible that your question simply won't receive the level of attention or kind of answers you seek. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @wolly In that [HINT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2971261/505767) there are all the information to solve the limit, If you want I can give some information more.

Comment: @wolly why do you ask it again? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$\;\cos \alpha-\cos\beta=-2\,\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\,\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2$$

so you get

$$\frac{\cos x-\cos2x}{\cos x-\cos3x}=\frac{\sin\frac{3x}2\;\sin\frac x2}{\sin2x\;\sin x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\ldots$$